# SQL Server 2005 frequent deadlocks

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, deadlock

we have a web application built using ASP.NET 4.0 (C#) and we are using SQL Server 2005 as the backend.

the application itself is a workflow engine where each record is attested by 4 role bearers over 18 days in a month.

we roughly have 200k records which come on 1st of each month.

during the 18 days - some people are looking and attesting records whereas system admin might be changing the ownership of these records.

my question or worry is that we often get deadlock issues in the database.

some user may have 10000 records in their kitty and they try to attest all records in one go whereas system admin may also change ownership in bulk for few thousand records and at that point we get deadlock and even when two or more users with laods of accounts try to attest - we get deadlocks.

We are extensively using stored procs with transactions. Is there a way to code for such situations?

or to simply avoid deadlocks.

Apologies for asking in such a haphazard manner but any hints or tips are welcome and if you need more info to under stand the issue then let me know.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions:

1) Use the same order for reading/writing data from/into tables.

Example #1 (read-write deadlock): Avoid creating a stored procedure `usp_ReadA_WriteB` that reads from A and then writes into B and another stored procedure `usp_ReadB_WriteA` that reads from B and then writes into A. Read this [blog post](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/16/readwrite-deadlock/) please.

Example #2 (write-write deadlock): Avoid creating a stored procedure `usp_WriteA_WriteB` that writes data into table A and then into table B and another stored procedure `usp_WriteB_writeA` that writes data into the same tables: table B and then into table A.

2) Minimize duration of transactions. Minimize the affected rows to reduce the number of locks. Be attention at 5000 locks threshold for [lock escalation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

3) Optimize your queries. For example: look for `[Clustered]{Index|Table}Scan`, `{Key|RID} Lookup` and  `Sort` operators in execution plans. Use indices but, also, try to minimize the number of indices and try to minimize the size of every index (first try to minimize the index key's size). Read this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2013/06/17/high-cpu-troubleshooting-with-dmv-queries.aspx), please.

Comment: Brilliant; thanks for your suggestions - let me do some reading.

Comment: Two more things: 4) During transaction you have to exclude any UI interaction (so, avoid `start transaction, wait for user input,  insert data, finish transaction`). 5) If you have long transactions which affects many rows you could store those rows into table variables and perform the final data modifications at the end of transaction (ex. 'BEGIN TRAN;...INSERT INTO @TableVarA SELECT...FROM ...UPDATE @TableVarA...INSERT INTO @TableVarB...DELETE @TableVarB...INSERT dbo.TableA SELECT FROM @TableVarA;UPDATE dbo.TableB SET...FROM @TableVarB;COMMIT;'). I used this solution with good results.